# Using composer to install third party symfony bundle

Tags: symfony-2.1, composer-php

Ok. Composer seems great.

But is more complex that deps method to add new bundles. I still don´t get it.

Please someone give me a complete example on how to add a third party bundle to a `symfony2 2.1.0-BETA4` installation.

The bundle I want to add is [this](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically:

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
}
```

Regarding to [the do](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)c, this is how it should be set up.

And if you **only** want this bundle (and not `DoctrineFixturesBundle`):

```
{
    "require": {
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: Thanks man!!!! I also had to run this command: `php composer.phar update doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`